# FlexBox with static and scrollable elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I would like to have the following:

1. Make `header` fixed, i.e. not scroll
2. Have `content` directly under `header`, i.e. if the height of `header` changes, there should be no overlap between the elements
3. Have `content` scroll vertically
4. As a side note: both `header` and `content` are flex containers
5. The `header` has a number of `<a>` elements with `href` linking to elements on `content`, which is used to scroll to the selected element on click

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this with:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```